# Linux freezes after hooking e.g. openat(2) system call using LKM

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-modules, c

I have written the following LKM for learning purposes, where the goal is to hook a system call (e.g. `openat(2)`).

The problem is that after successfully disabling `CR0.WP`, and setting `sys_call_table[__NR_openat]` to the hook, the system freezes.

Can anyone with deep knowledge of the Linux kernel comment on why this happens?

**Note**:

In order to run the LKM, you either have to replace `CAP_SET_EMPTY_OFFSET` and `SYS_CALL_TABLE_OFFSET` with the respective offsets for your kernel, or just hardcode the address of the `sys_call_table` obtained by `sudo cat /proc/kallsyms | grep sys_call_table`.

**Code**:

```
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/capability.h>
#include <linux/set_memory.h> /* Needed by set_memory_rw */

/*
 * Avoid tainting the kernel, however the kernel will still be tainted if the
 * module is not signed
 */
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

#define CAP_SET_EMPTY_OFFSET 0x45fe0
#define SYS_CALL_TABLE_OFFSET 0x2e0

static unsigned long* __sys_call_table;

unsigned long *find_sys_call_table(void)
{
   unsigned long rodata_start;
   rodata_start = (unsigned long)&__cap_empty_set - CAP_SET_EMPTY_OFFSET;
   return (unsigned long*)(rodata_start + SYS_CALL_TABLE_OFFSET);
}

static inline void __write_cr0(unsigned long val)
{
   asm volatile ("mov %0, %%cr0": : "r" (val));
}

static inline void disable_write_protection(void)
{
   preempt_disable();
   barrier();
   __write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~ 0x00010000));
}

static inline void enable_write_protection(void)
{
   __write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x00010000);
   barrier();
   preempt_enable();
}
    
typedef asmlinkage long (*orig_openat_t)(int, const char*, int, umode_t);
orig_openat_t orig_openat;

asmlinkage long
hooked_openat(int dirfd, const char __user* pathname, int flags, umode_t mode)
{
   //printk(KERN_INFO "%s: hooked openat\n", __func__);
   return orig_openat(dirfd, pathname, flags, mode);
}


static int __init syscall_init(void)
{
   printk(KERN_DEBUG "%s: started\n", __func__);

   printk(KERN_INFO "%s: cr0: %lx\n", __func__, read_cr0());

   __sys_call_table = find_sys_call_table();
   printk(KERN_INFO "%s: __sys_call_table: %px\n", __func__, __sys_call_table);

   orig_openat = (orig_openat_t)__sys_call_table[__NR_openat];
   printk(KERN_INFO "%s: orig_openat: %px\n", __func__, (void*)orig_openat);

   disable_write_protection();
   printk(KERN_INFO "%s: cr0: %lx\n", __func__, read_cr0());

   __sys_call_table[__NR_openat] = (unsigned long)hooked_openat;
   printk(KERN_INFO "%s: hooked_openat: %px\n", __func__, (void*)hooked_openat);

   enable_write_protection();
   printk(KERN_INFO "%s: cr0: %lx\n", __func__, read_cr0());

   return 0;
}

static void __exit syscall_release(void)
{
   disable_write_protection();
   __sys_call_table[__NR_openat] = (unsigned long)orig_openat;
   enable_write_protection();

   printk(KERN_DEBUG "%s: exited\n", __func__);
}

/* set the entry point of the module */
module_init(syscall_init);
/* set the exit point of the module */
module_exit(syscall_release);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you’re not setting `orig_openat` anywhere; you’d need

```c
orig_openat = (orig_openat_t) _sys_call_table[__NR_openat];
_sys_call_table[__NR_openat] = (unsigned long)hooked_openat;
```

when hooking the call.

Comment: Thanks. Don’t know why that line was lost, when I copied the code, so that’s not the problem. The system freezes on `insmod` not `rmmod`. I have got a hint that it might have something to do with system call wrappers. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: Could you update your question to show the code you’re actually using? The wrapper is a good point; you might need to declare your hook function as a syscall itself, because the actual syscall entry point is typically an unmarshalling function.

Comment: I see that Debian has the following config enabled, implying syscall wrappers: `$ cat /boot/config-5.8.0-50-generic | grep CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER
CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER=y`

Comment: I have updated the code